# How to call selectedindexchange event from buttonclick event?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one form.In that form base on first dropdownlist's item,second get populated.first dropdownlist contain class,onselection of class,appropriate subject name(only 1) get populated.This is working properly.Onbutton click event of update button,I am fetching value from database and assigning to control.First dropdownlist is filled at page load.But my second dropdownlist get filled only after firstdropdownlist's item selection.I am assigning year to first dropdownlist.But when I am trying to assign a subjectname to second,it is already empty.How to call selectedindexchange of firstdownlist in update button click event.

Comment: You can write a method for this and in that method fetch data based on firstDropdDown selectedItem value. now when you click update button , call this method and also call the same method on selectedIndexChange of first dropDwon. that will save your time for writing extra code. use same method for both the events

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the Event Handler for the dropdownlist event in your Update Button click event as:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
{
```

Also, You can set the `SelectedIndex` of dropdown and call the handler as:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 2;
       DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
     // Note that if the arguments sender and e are not being used, 
     // pass null args like  below rather than creating new objects:   
       DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
}
```